# AngularJS form validation for password confirm

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a simple user registration form in my Angular1x app. I want to ensure that 'password' and 'password_confirm match. If they do not match the form should be invalid. I can display validation messages if the input does not match but the form is not invalid menaing that it can be submitted:

```
<div class="form-group input text required " ng-class="{'has-error': userRegister.$submitted && password !== password_confirm}">
     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="password_confirm" placeholder="Password Confirm" ng-model="password_confirm" equals="{{password}}" required="required" id="password-confirm" />
</div>
```

I tried adding the 'equals' attribute which I read aboiut, but again it does not invalid the form.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the `equals="{{passwor}}d" ` just a tippo?

Comment: It's a typo - question updated

Answer (score 1):

I've created a small [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q9wroh1y/) that does the trick with `ng-pattern="(password)"` So the second input could look like this:

```
 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="password_confirm" placeholder="Password Confirm" ng-model="password_confirm" ng-pattern="(password)" required="required" id="password-confirm" />
```

Comment: This works perfectly with invalid form status if the password do not match.

Comment: having tested this the solution doesn't work - see my modified fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c58dfeka/

Comment: Update at https://jsfiddle.net/sL0ojhe9/ the pattern is based on the model variable of the first password.